# SQL Server, Does 'sum' funcation works fine in large tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building a market sell points system using C# winForms, SQL Server 2014
My problem is the idea of storing the products and quantities
the program should display the quantity of some product when making a new sell bill
so before user make a sell he should know the quantity of this product, and see if it enough for the order or not
i created this table for items
Item_ID,     Item,     Buy_Price,     Sell_Price,     Quantity

but this makes confusions when user edit some bills , sell bills or buy bills
so for example when user edit some buy bill(invoice), edit the quantity in the buy bill
then the product quantity cell in items table will not match the quantity in buybills table
so i want to make it little more dynamic and remove the quantity cell from items table
and using the bills table to get the quantity of any item
that means when user search for an item(Product) to sell, system uses a sum funcation buy sql statement
quantity = sum(item_quantity) in buy_bills - sum(item_quantity) in sell_bills
does it works? or this will be so heavey when databases size and records count get larger?

Comment: Performance is definitely something that needs to be tested on your data in your environment.  There is no *a priori* reason to assume that the processing is unreasonable.

Comment: what i meant that is what ever user edits bills, the quantity will be the total of these bills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is not related to SUM function as such (it will sum up whatever you put in your query and rather quickly - in general) but with concept of detecting available quantities. Assuming that there is more than one selling point it will be impossible to get accurate available quantity of any product if you do not provide some form of concurrency control.

So, you may use sum from table where you have history of buy or sell of products. But, before you accept any change you need to put some lock to prevent other sellers to change (sell) same quantity. After you have committed one sell you may allow other sellers to continue with their activities assuring that you refresh currently presented items quantities.

Do have in mind that this scenario is one of the basic ones that may occur in any multiuser business application.

So, to conclude, do provide

1. One point in time where you are sure that existing stock cannot be lowered
2. SUM in the way you see fit for your application
3. Refresh any pending sale with new quantities

Comment: So you're saying that it's not a problem to make this calculation that gets the item quantity, i'm just afraid because the user will use this statement repeatly all day, and will need it to be fast to take the next order you know, So after long time there will be a huge number of records that need to be calculated to get the quantity, and i can't know what will be the performance then, and this is example of my statement

Comment: SELECT SUM(all input's) - SELECT SUM(all output's)

Comment: Approach where you use SUM from turnover table from performance point of view depends on number of transactions and number of users. You should have some expectations in this regard. If you expect tens or hundreds of users you may consider some kind of end-of-day process where you will aggregate totals per item and you would only SUM daily turnover. Bigger problem is ability of two or more users to concurrently pick up current total per item and do the sale. If this is not handled your users will be able to sell more than they have.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it little more dynamic and remove the quantity cell from items table and using the bills table to get the quantity of any item that means when user search for an item(Product) to sell, system uses a sum funcation buy sql statement quantity = sum(item_quantity) in buy_bills - sum(item_quantity) in sell_bills does it works?

Assuming you have your syntax correct, it is possible to sum a column using the sum function. You can subtract two sums in a single statement. Ie, SUM(Column_1) - SUM(Column2) AS Column3. This assumes that you have everything else set up correctly.

> or this will be so heavey when databases size and records count get larger?

This is 100% relative to your database setup and not answerable here. It is possible that it will slow down when the database gets larger. But, if your database is set up correctly, it should not be by much.

It is also possible, later on, to get around that issue by pre-loading the data.

Comment: What do you mean *It is also possible, later on, to get around that issue by pre-loading the data.*